# I get "(variablename) is null" when trying to edit dom elements inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6, p5.js

I don't know jQuery and I'm trying to use only ECMAScript (ES6) and I found on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp) a way to edit DOM elements inside an `<iframe>`

My code is exactly the same:

```
let iframe = document.getElementById("music");
let elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("player");
elmnt.play();
```

I have an iframe tag with id="music" and inside an audio tag with id="player". The code should play the audio source when the page is loaded, it works but I still get the error in the console and I can't interact with volume with ES6.

but I get: "TypeError: elmnt is null (sketch: line 29)"

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/mark_karrica_/pen/zgxyVL

(I'm using the p5.js library but I don't think th problem is related to that)

Comment: so sounds like you did not find the element....

Comment: Make sure iframe has loaded before trying to access elements inside it

Comment: @charlietfl How can I be sure the iframe has loaded? Is there a callback or something?

Comment: @Amy https://codepen.io/mark_karrica_/pen/zgxyVL

Comment: @Amy https://imgur.com/Sac7rAs you can see in the top of the console that error

Comment: @SuzannaBenedetti I see now, okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running before the iframe has finished loading.  You can prevent this by setting up your code to run after the frame has loaded.  `iframe` elements have a `load` event you can attach event handlers to.

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="..." onload="iframeLoaded()"></iframe>
```

Here, I have attached the event handler `iframeLoaded` to the frame's `load` event.  You then stick your code inside that method:

```
function iframeLoaded() {
    let iframe = document.getElementById("music");
    let elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("player");
    elmnt.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I googled and used this: `if (iframe.readyState == 'complete'){}` I think there's no difference between what you posted and what I used

Comment: That line inside that event handler is not necessary, as the `load` event is only emitted once the iframe is ready.  You are welcome to post your own solution as a separate answer.

Comment: "SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object (sketch: line 6)" but at least it tries to execute the code

Comment: I suggest asking a new question.  Browsers provide a lot of security around iframes, which you can read about [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting).